Reading PDF using iText (7.1.15) with C# gives \uXXX characters
I am trying to read a PDF file with both English and Hebrew text.
The GetTextFromPage method gives me the following long, weird string:
"\v 2 : \v 1 3 - #\nG \u0003 \f \n \b \r \v \u0013 \u000f \u0014 \u0010 \v \u0014 \n \v \u0014 \u000e \f \n \f \t \f \v \t \u0010 \f \u000e \f \n \f \t \f \v \t \u0010 \f \u000e \f \b \f \v \t \v \n M \b P \b L\nI Z \a G P [ O Z J R [ E F N E T J [\n\" \u001b \u0014 % \u001e \u001f \u001d \u0010 \u001c \u0016 \u001d \u0018 \u0014 \u0014 \u001d \u0018 \u0016 \u001d \u0014 \u0018 \u001f \u0010 \u0017 !\n\b

Looking at the Document Properties, under Fonts I see the following:
David (Embedded Subset)
Type: TrueType (CID)
Encoding: Custom
David, Bold (Embedded Subset)
Type: TrueType (CID)
Encoding: Custom
Any ideas how to fix it?
Thank you
Yaniv

It looks likely that the PDF does not contain the information required for text extraction from text drawing operations. Without the PDF it's hard to tell for sure, though.

@mkl thanks. the PDF contains sensitive info and cannot be shared here... can I send it over to you for a quick review? I appreciate your help.

@Yaniv "can I send it over to you for a quick review?" - theoretically yes, but I'm mostly on my smart phone only for the rest of the year and, therefore, cannot analyze.

i you want to create pdf with txt file with Encoding: Custom to do direct for my past experience i am using this method to do this kind of work
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

StringBuilder extractedText = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    string pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
    extractedText.Append(pageText);
}

pdfReader.Close();
return extractedText.ToString();

Your wrong in i thing Custom Encoding and Font Usage
and for that resolve this
Custom Encoding: The strange characters like \u0003 \f \n \b suggest that the encoding is not being decoded properly. iText might not handle this custom encoding by default. You may need to create a custom extraction strategy to properly decode these characters into the correct Hebrew text.
Font Usage: The "David" font in your PDF is embedded as a subset with a custom encoding. This might make it hard for iText to map the characters correctly. You can use a tool like pdffonts to check how characters are mapped to ensure proper extraction.
after doing this check Official iText Documentation
If the default methods don’t work, check iText’s official documentation for dealing with custom encodings. You can find details on how to handle these cases and apply similar techniques in C# as described for Java.
with this method if not work then check this site https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/7.1.15/index.html?com%2Fitextpdf%2Fio%2Ffont%2FIExtraEncoding.html= this is officialapi from iText as well check this How to get the text position from the pdf page in iText 7

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
